# Nested JSON structure serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I am creating a Jjava application which pass json data to NodejS to fetch data from database. The Java app can include one or multiple attribute to select from DB, add constraints like order by, greater than etc. So its getting me puzzle to how to save these data in Java data structure.

One sample JSON strucure is:

```
{
    "query": {},
    "select": {},
    "sort": {},
    "limit": -1
}
```

Here `query` key contains column_name of table and contstraints eg.

```
{
    "query": {
        "column_name1": {
            "greaterthan": "value",
            "lessthan": "value"
        },
        "column_name2": {
            "equalto": "value"
        }
    },
    "select": {},
    "sort": {},
    "limit": -1
}
```

The `select` key keeps name of columns to select in query eg:

```
{
    "query": {
        "column_name1": {
            "greaterthan": "value",
            "lessthan": "value"
        },
        "column_name2": {
            "equalto": "value"
        }
    },
    "select": {
        "column_name1": 1,
        "column_name2": "1andsoon"
    },
    "sort": {},
    "limit": -1
}
```

`sort` keeps column names for `ORDER BY` operation and `limit` is for number of rows to select.

Comment: Are you using the structure of thes JSON documents in Java? How?

Comment: yes, i am creating some methods like for equalTo(columnName, value), greaterThan(columnName, value). so internally i need to save these data and make json structure and pass it to nodejs

Comment: presently I am trying to save these data using nested HashMap. but i feel its not a correct way. that's why i posted this problem here.

Comment: did you here about JSONObject library in java? from here http://www.json.org/java/ ? You can preserve current json structure, also you have method get() - to retrive value that must present, like object.get(id) or method opt to retrieve object that MAY present, like object.opt(comment), and return empty string when it is not present